# CSS transitions don't affect replaced node

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

Why does showLoadingAndResetAnimation not fade-in correctly, but showLoading does? Instead of fading in, the element becomes immediately opaque.
https://jsfiddle.net/q56a3mjj/18/

```
function showLoading() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0];
    elem.style.opacity = 1;
}

/* As per css-tricks.com, I restart the animation by        *
* replacing the animated node with a deep-copy of itself    *
* https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/             */
function showLoadingAndResetAnimation() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0];
    var newElem = elem.cloneNode(true);
    elem.parentNode.replaceChild(newElem, elem);
    newElem.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

EDIT: I believe this happens because the browser doesn't ever see the newElem as having an `opacity: 0`, so it doesn't think it's transitioning from 0. Adding a 20ms timeout works.

Comment: are you open to a different solution to what you want to achieve ? like just `css` and no `javascript` ?

Comment: Yes, just CSS would be great.
Also, if people downvote can you please explain why (so I don't do it again next time)?

Comment: "I believe this happens because the browser doesn't ever see the newElem as having an opacity: 0, so it doesn't think it's transitioning from 0." That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're creating an element ( replacing the original ) and CSS3 transition-delay event will be fired for elements after being live.

you can do the animation you want by removing your `javascript` and use this :

```
@keyframes moveRight {
    0%   {left: 0; opacity : 0}
    50%   {opacity : 1}
    99% {left: 650px; opacity : 0}
    100% {left:0; opacity: 0;}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q56a3mjj/33/

Comment: Sorry, this would work fine for some cases but unfortunately not mine. I need to be able to have an infinitely looping animation until something loads, then it will be hidden. When something else needs to load the animation will be reset and shown again.

Comment: this is an infinite animation loop, and you can apply it on an element ( `main` in your case ) and hide the element when something loads, and if you want to restart it, simply show the element again, anyways, if adding 20ms timeout works for you then great, i'm glad you could work it out :)

Comment: Yes, but showing the element again resumes the animation from where it left off (e.g. mine moves across the top of a div, would look weird if it started half way)

Comment: sorry, i meant not just the visibility but something like adding and removing a class, you add it when loading and remove it once finished,  this will reset the animation, here's an example of what i mean https://jsfiddle.net/q56a3mjj/53/